# How to Add Value in Indicator in Linear Scale Component on SCADA Ignition

Tags: ignition, scada-ignition

I used a `Linear Scale` `Component` using Ignition 7.8 to display a fuel level like this:

[image]

I want to indicate the current value of the fuel in the same scale. But as I browse through the property of the `Linear Scale` `Component`, I couldn't any property resembling `Value`, `Text`, `Number`, or alike.

How can I display the `Value` in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a data set for that component that includes an indicator arrow or line. Then, use Cell Bindings to bind a tag to that indicator arrow.

Demo is here:
https://inductiveuniversity.com/video/cell-update-binding?r=/course/components-property-binding

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the end I decided to post it in the Inductive Automation forum a couple of days ago and already got the answer there (since there seems to be more people specialized in Ignition there).  But thanks nevertheless. Voted up +10. ;)